# SSL_connect() not returning

Tags: c, sockets, ssl, openssl, client

I'm trying to create server-client program using SSL. I'm having a little trouble with SSL_connect(): when I call it, it won't return ever again, it just hangs there, the client program keeps running forever and the server is stalled waiting for the handshake to finish. Once I kill the client-process, server would say the safe-connection failed, so I'm almost 100% sure it's not server's fault, since it waits for a connection, and tries to accept it (SSL_accept()) normally.

Also, when my client calls SSL_connect() it prints a lot of trash characters on my stdout, don't know why.

Here's the code for my connect function:

```
if((sslconnection = SSL_new(ctx)) == NULL){
    return NULL;
}

if(SSL_set_fd(sslconnection, socketd) != 1){
    return NULL;
}

printf("We have no problem until here\n");

if((debug = SSL_connect(sslconnection)) == 1){
    printf("You won't see this, it's hanged\n");
    return sslconnection;
}
printf("Neither will you see this\n");
```

CTX and socketd are previously initialized, of course.
Thanks in advance, guys, any help will be gladly welcome!

**EDIT:** If I use the SSLv23_method() to create my SSL context, when the client hangs, if I press 'enter' a few times, it will show on the terminal this message:

```
error:1408F10B:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_RECORD:wrong version number
```

Otherwise, if I use the SSLv3_method(), pressing 'enter' will give me this message:

```
error:140770FC:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown protocol
```

I guess there's a problem with SSL versions of my client-server programs, which is pretty weird since they use the same function to initialize their own SSL_ctx, therefore they use the same SSLvX_method() to create the context, so it makes no sense to me that they don't understand each other's SSL version...

Comment: There's a few "SSL_connect hang" question on Stack Overflow. Perhaps one of them could help you: [ssl_connect hang site:stackoverflow.com](http://www.google.com/search?q=ssl_connect+hang+site%3Astackoverflow.com).

Comment: If you get SSL errors while pressing enter you probably attached stdin (e.g. file descriptor 0) with SSL_set_fd, but not the fd connected to the other side. Please check, that socketfd is really your connected socket, before you call SSL_connect.

Comment: Embarassing: I was giving my connect function a random-initialized non-used int as the socket instead of the one I opened for it, product of code I copied from the server file and then modified...Thank you very much Steffen, you saved me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it helps someone out there: comes out that it was a wrong socket descriptor I was using to do the SSL_connect(), just as Steffen said. I got messed up with the descriptors at some point of the code.